NetworkManager link-local fallback connection fails when setting MAC address
I'm trying to create a fallback to a link-local ip address in linux NetworkManager if the DHCP fails.
Currently I'm trying to set it up like in this answer (two connections in the same interface, one with a limited amount of dhcp retries, and then another with a lower priority that activates if the first one fails to get a DHCP address too many times), except that the fallback connection has ipv4.method "link-local" instead of "manual": https://askubuntu.com/a/1225863
This works. However, I also need to randomize MAC addresses because otherwise there are duplicates on the network (the disk will be imaged and copied to other machines). I try to change this by changing the setting 802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address to "stable".
This successfully changes the MAC address, however it breaks the link-local fallback for some reason. The first connection still works if there is a DHCP server, I get an ip address and the MAC is now randomized.
But when there is no DHCP server, now it's like the fallback connection doesn't exist, nothing happens. Instead of randomized MAC address, I have also tried a specified MAC address, with the same problem. The link-local fallback connection only activates successfully if the cloned MAC address setting of the first connection is blank.
I have also tried to set the same MAC address, and stable-id setting, on both the main and the fallback connection, to no avail.
Does anyone have any ideas why this happens?

I'm not sure I understand how cloning the disk leads to needing to randomize the MAC address? The address comes from the Ethernet interface, not from your disk, doesn't it?

@grawity_u1686 I don't know either, but it does. The issue is verified.

@grawity_u1686 But if there is a way to change the underlying MAC address that the OS reads from the interface instead of spoofing it with NetworkManager, then maybe that would fix the problem

Well, true, but normally you wouldn't have the problem. Where specifically are you seeing the duplicate MAC address – do you see it on the machines themselves (like in ip link or ifconfig) or do you see it in your DHCP server (machines fighting over a DHCP lease)? If the latter, I suspect that the duplicate ID isn't a MAC address at all.

It is actually a duplicate permanent address. I see it in ip addr, and in /sys/class/net/eth0/address.
It might be a bug with this relatively obscure distro/cpu combination because I see other similar reports in the past, like this: https://forum.armbian.com/topic/14653-rock64-same-mac-on-two-boards/
